# How to move items left and right in an html table using css? -

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have 6 `<td>`s in my `<tr>`s and I want the last 3 in each row to all be closer together. How can I move them?

Here is my html:

```
<p> Test.com Funtown <div><a href="#">Click Here</a></div> </p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusRunning">R</td>
        <td>My First Try</td>
        <td>100 / 250 plays</td>
        <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusQueued">1</td>
        <td>The best try</td>
        <td>0 / 250 plays</td>
        <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusIncomplete"> </td>
        <td>Could be better</td>
        <td>0 / 50 plays</td>
        <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my css:

```
p {
}
div a { 
}
table {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  text-align:right;      
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
}

table tr       {background:#fff;}
table tr:hover {background:#EBF7FC;}

table tr       td             {padding:6px 8px;}
table tr       td:first-child {border-left: 3px solid #fff;}
table tr       td:last-child  {border-right:3px solid #fff;} 
table tr:hover td:first-child {border-left: 3px solid #4EB2E2;}
table tr:hover td:last-child  {border-right:3px solid #4EB2E2;}

table tr td:nth-child(1){
  color:#fff;
  width: 33px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.statusRunning {
   background-color: #5AD427;
}
.statusQueued {
   background-color: #A4E786;
}
.statusIncomplete {
   background-color: #FFCC00;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2){
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: there are 18 <td> elements in your table, and there are 6 per row. What do you mean when you say you want the last 3 "close together" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just put them all into the same `<td>` and add margin/padding to the `<a>` element inside the `<td>`then you could add whatever number of links you want in there.

here is a fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/D7sTY/

Html

```
  <tr>
    <td class="statusRunning">R</td>
    <td>My First Try</td>
    <td>100 / 250 plays</td>
    <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Players</a><a href="#">Duplicate</a><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
  </tr>
```

CSS

```
.tightcell a
{
    margin: 0 2px;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Target them separately using CSS and remove/decrease the padding.

```
table tr td:nth-child(4), table tr td:nth-child(5), table tr td:nth-child(6){  
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4Dw5/2/

I completely removed the padding on them, you might want to add a few pixels though.

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child(n+4)` like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/rz8n9/2/)):

```
td:nth-child(n+4){
    padding: 0;   
}
```

Here's a preview:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but oddly when I put the same code in it did nothing to my table... Would if have something to do with the fact that I am using SASS with Zurb Foundation 5? Otherwise I'm not sure what to do to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Set id atribute of HTML control to the css class included in your .css file
and add following code in your .css file

```
<HTMLControl id="id">

#id{
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
enter code here}
```